# Slot is wider than the blades it comes with

Tags: saw

I recently tore apart a Rockwell Bladerunner RK7320 because the factory blades (T-slot) kept flying out almost impacting my eye, and the blade twists whenever the locking mechanism is held on the blade.
To my complete surprise, the slot inside the machine is 0.1mm wide exactly, and the blades I have are on average 0.0425mm wide. Ranging from a minimum of 0.039mm to a max of 0.058mm. The bearings at the top that support the blade is about the same distance wide, 0.1mm.

I've scoured across the internet, and to various hardware stores, to come to the conclusion that the machine I have, was fitted with the wrong sized slotted rod, because the blades are almost all the same range in thickness. If I had another RK7320 saw to compare, I can say that the company made a gigantic error, if I had another different jigsaw, I'd say there is probably a reason why the slot is way bigger than the blades.

If anyone has an answer for why this is, please let me know.
If not, I will be cutting some T slots off other blades to epoxy to the blades I have so they can fit down in the slot that it was made for, and they don't fly out of the machine, or twist.

Comment: Is this a new saw?  Or still under warranty?

Comment: I have one with a latch and one that requires an Allen key. Guess which one the blade has never flew out of.

Comment: Are the units in the question correct? Or does mm mean something other than millimetre? Aluminium foil is about 0.02mm thick. 1mm seems like a more realistic thickness for a saw blade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their was junk at the bottom of the blade fixture, and it only took a fraction of material for the blade to behave erratic. I took apart the blade runner completely and cleaned it. I don't know what I did other than that, but after that it ran completely fine.

Inside the slot down past the top of it, I believe it's a taper from 0.1mm down to the size of the blades. This allows the blades to flex so they don't completely snap when horizontal force is applied to the blade.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't epoxy blades together. The only safe way to join metal blades is to tig weld them together and polish it for a perfect bond as strong or stronger than the parent metal. An epoxied blade is liable fly apart to put one through your eye. - Trust me. I've been a welder longer the majority of my life, and I've welded almost every common and uncommon metal under the sun, including epoxy welds.

As to where you can buy .1 mm thick blades? Bosch (German made). The .04" thick blades are exactly 1.016mm thick. 
https://www.boschtools.com/us/en/boschtools-ocs/t-shank-jig-saw-blades-for-metal-t227d-30858-p/

Comment: I agree not to try epoxy, at work on our big band saw I spot weld blades together. +